# GridView Loads the duplicate images and Text (using EndlessScrollListener)

Tags: android, scroll, android-asynctask, android-gridview

I have a custom gridVIew With an ImageView and a TextView in it, and I have set the gridView as a it show 2 coloumns. here is the code of custom_grid_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget44"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBookCover"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_image_borders"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/book5" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_BookTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textColorHighlight="#656565" >
</TextView>
```

and here is the layout of gridview.xml

```
 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Rel_Spinner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

- Its loading the images from server and showing the correct images and text for the first time, as I have implemented the EndlessScrollListner class in my project.
- In the first itration im loading 12 images from the server, when i Scroll down the gridView to end it sends the second request to Load 12 more images and text from the server.
- Here the actual problem starts its loading the same images and text.
- Please have a look on my bulky code and tell where I am commeting the mistake.

public class Home extends Activity {
    static final String URL = "http://www.shiaislamiclibrary.com/requesthandler.ashx";

```
static final String KEY_ITEM = "Book"; // parent node
static final String KEY_BOOKAUTHOR = "book_author";
static final String KEY_BOOKRATING = "BookRating";
static final String KEY_BOOKID = "BookID";
static final String KEY_BOOKDESC = "BookDescription";
static final String KEY_BOOKDATEPUBLISHED = "DatePublished";
static final String KEY_BOOKTITLE = "BookTitle";
static final String KEY_BOOKCODE = "BookCode";
static final String KEY_BOOKIMAGE = "BookImage";
static final String KEY_ITEM_BOOKs_LIMIT = "Result"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ITEM_TOTAL_BOOKS = "TotalBooks";

    static ArrayList<String> BookTitle = null;
static ArrayList<Integer> BookRating = null;
static ArrayList<String> BookDescription = null;
static ArrayList<String> BookCoverPhotos = null;
static ArrayList<String> BookAuther = null;
static ArrayList<String> BookIDs = null;
static ArrayList<String> BookCode = null;
static ArrayList<String> BookPublishDate = null;
static ArrayList<String> ImageByte = null;
static ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = null;
static int initialIndex = 12;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());
if (BookTitle == null) {
                BookTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
                BookRating = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                BookDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
                BookIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
                BookCode = new ArrayList<String>();
                BookCoverPhotos = new ArrayList<String>();
                BookAuther = new ArrayList<String>();
                BookPublishDate = new ArrayList<String>();
                ImageByte = new ArrayList<String>();
                bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
                new UIThread().execute(URL, initialIndex + "");
                // Log.i("If", BookTitle + "");
            } else {

                // Log.i("else", BookTitle + "");
                ImageAdapter adapter2 = new ImageAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                        act);
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter2);

            }
```

Im using AsynkTaks to download the images from server. here is the code

```
private class UIThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getBaseContext(), act);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(),
                "Acumlating Books from server...",
                "This may Take a few seconds.\nPlease Wait...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String URL = params[0];
        int initialIndex = Integer.valueOf(params[1]);
        Log.i("params", params[1] + "");

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String XMLString = parser.getXmlFromUrl_FeaturedBooks(URL,
                initialIndex);

        Home.initialIndex = Home.initialIndex + 12;
        Log.i("Home.initialIndex", Home.initialIndex + "");

        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(XMLString);
        NodeList nlBooksLimit = doc
                .getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM_BOOKs_LIMIT);
        Element eLimit = (Element) nlBooksLimit.item(0);

        String totalBooks = parser.getValue(eLimit, KEY_ITEM_TOTAL_BOOKS);
        Log.i("totalBooks", totalBooks + "");
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        // looping through all item nodes <item>

        Bitmap imageNotFound = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.defaultcoverphoto);

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            try {
                BookRating.add(Integer.valueOf(parser.getValue(e,
                        KEY_BOOKRATING)));
                // Log.i("Rating Try", BookRating.get(i) + "");

            } catch (Exception e2) {
                BookRating.add(0);
                // Log.i("Rating Catch", BookRating + "");
            }

            BookDescription.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKDESC));
            BookTitle.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKTITLE));
            BookCoverPhotos.add("http://shiaislamicbooks.com/books_Snaps/"
                    + parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKCODE) + "/1_thumb.jpg");
            BookAuther.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKAUTHOR));
            BookPublishDate.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKDATEPUBLISHED));
            BookIDs.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKID));
            BookCode.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKCODE));
            // Log.i("URLs & Desc", BookCoverPhotos.toString());

            try {
                bookImageURL = new URL(BookCoverPhotos.get(i));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                // Log.i("URL", "ERROR at image position" + i + "");
            }

            try {
                bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bookImageURL
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());
                bitmapArray.add(bitMapImage);
                publishProgress(i + 1);

            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                bitmapArray.add(imageNotFound);
                // Log.i("File Not Found", bookImageURL + "");
            }

        }

        Log.i("Book Title", BookTitle + "");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressDialog.setMessage(values[0]
                + " Book(s) found \nPlease wait...");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and here is the EndlessScrollListner.java code. which send the request to sever again to download when the scroll reaches to the bottom of the gridView.

```
private class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

    private int visibleThreshold = 0;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }
        }
        if (!loading
                && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
            // but you can call any function here.
            new UIThread().execute(URL, Home.initialIndex + "");
            Log.i("Reached", "End");
            Log.i("Home.initialIndex", Home.initialIndex + "");
            loading = true;
        }
    }
```

here are 2 pictures to make you more clear my question.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although pretty late, but I just ran into the same problem. Its happening because of the adapter's `getView` method. 
In your `ImageAdapter`, if the `getView` function reuses the view already created then this might be the reason for your image repetition. If the code looks like below, then it is supposed to be changed like the second code snippet to download new images coming from load more.

`Snippet 1`

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageview;
    if(v == null)
    {
        imageview = new ImageView(mcontext);
        imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250,250));
        imageview.setPadding(0,0,10,10);
        imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        new DownloadImageTask(imageview).execute(arr.get(position).imageUrl);
    }
    else
        imageview = (ImageView) v;

   return imageview;
}
```

`Snippet 2`

```
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageview;
    if(v == null)
    {
        imageview = new ImageView(mcontext);
        imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250,250));
        imageview.setPadding(0,0,10,10);
        imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    }
    else
        imageview = (ImageView) v;
    new DownloadImageTask(imageview).execute(arr.get(position).imageUrl);
   return imageview;
}
```

Or probably create a new view altogether but then you may need to handle `virtualization` and `reusability` of the `gridView`/`listView` by yourself.